# nuget restore does not copy config file

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-standard

My .netstandard2.0 package packs a config file within the nuget package, it was packed with this directive:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="apps.config" Pack="True" PackagePath="lib/$(TargetFramework)">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Using the nuget package explorer, i can see that the file is indeed packed in the nuget package, put under the same directory as the .dll file.

Then I added this package into another project using the install-package command, but when run the app, only the .dll file is copied into bin\debug, not the config file. How can I copy the config file as well when doing a restore?

Comment: Are you using a nuspec file to create your nuget package?

Comment: @techvice i didn't create a nuspec file, i just use the .csproj file with `dotnet pack`.

Answer (score 1):

Use NuGet's `contentFiles` feature to include content to be consumed by the project. If you package the file as `Content` item instead of `None` and add the `PackageCopyToOutput="true"` metadata, NuGet will create the right paths and nuspec content:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="apps.config" />
  <Content Include="apps.config" Pack="true" PackageCopyToOutput="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, what is the `<None Remove...>` line for?

Comment: The default patterns will include the item as none by default (it will be visible in solution explorer.) If you change the build action "None" to "Content", vs should change the project file already in this way. It just makes sure that this is the item you'll see in the solution explorer and there aren't two items with different build actions but the same.

Comment: sorry I tried but it's not working, the file is packed into the nupkg file, but the config file is not copied when doing restore.

Comment: it should be in the build output

Comment: content is never copied to consuming projects on restore with `PackageReference`. that is a now-deprecated feature of packages.config with content folders

Comment: It’s not in bin/Debug, only dll is there

Comment: is the consuming project a .net core / asp.net core project or a classic .net project? use `PackageReference` to use this feature or you'll have to write custom msbuild scripts to make sure this works

Comment: It’s a .net Wpf app